# Recovering files from previous .rdata in R

Tags: r

As my R was facing trouble while loading workspace I run command

```
   rm(list=ls()) and unlink(".RData")
```

But I had some unsaved files(code). Is there a way to recover them back?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What editor do you use? Perhaps have a look there.

Comment: RStudio is my editor. Where do I check there.

Comment: I got it. I checked Rstudio server and I recovered all my files. Thank you